# Which languages ​are supported by flutter internationalization

Tags: flutter, internationalization, flutter-intl

I know that flutter internationalization can support many languages, but I can’t find out which languages ​​it supports. Where can I find this information?

Comment: thanks,but I did not  see anything like a language list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) is Flutters guide to setting up internationalizing. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations-library.html) you can find the languages support by the `flutter_localizations` library.